# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"' when running django-admin.exe using python

Tags: python, django, python-3.6

i have my python installed in my desktop the version is python 3.6.4. Now i tried to create a Virtual environment: Windows using this command below

```
C:\Users\YOUR Name\djangogirls1> python -m venv myvenv
```

and this has been successfully created a myvenv folder inside djangogirls1 folder. Now i start to run my virtual environment by running:

```
C:\Users\YOUR Name\djangogirls1> myvenv\Scripts\activate
```

Now i tried to copy the Django-2.0.5 folder and files inside to folder djangogirls1 myvenv folder then tried to run the command like this

```
(myvenv) C:\Users\YOUR Name\Documents\djangogirls1>python -m django --version
2.0.5
```

now my Django version is 2.0.5 and i think my django is successfully installed.

Now my Python is located in:

```
C:\Program Files\Python36
```

inside my `C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts` i added two files which is

```
django-admin.exe and django-admin.py
```

this is my django-admin.py file

```
#!C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
    management.execute_from_command_line()
```

when i tried to run this command `Create project: Windows`

```
(myvenv) C:\Users\YOUR Name\Documents\djangogirls1>django-admin.exe startpoject mysite .
```

i get this line of error

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

My pip is also updated. I dont know why i get the error. Also in my environmental variables i added the path

```
C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\django-admin.exe\
```

Can someone help me figured this thing out? Im stuck on this one. Any help is muchly Appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1):

`django-admin.py startproject mysite` instead of '.exe' '.py' should come .

PS : I would have commented but i do not have  sufficient reputation

Comment: its okay now. the problem that i encounter is that the IP address in the company. some download access is being blocked. i tried it installing at my home. And it really works

Answer (score 0):

I think u have changed the location of `python.exe`. so open `django-admin.py` file and change the path here.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't have multiple paths for pip in env.variables and maintain one version of python globally in your system ... this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I faced when I renamed my root folder name after creating the virtual environment and installed django.

**Solution**:
I created virtual environment again and installed django.
The main problem is with the path in django-admin.py in your virtual_environment/Scripts

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal run `pip install django` in the **root folder** before you run `django-admin startproject ..`. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
python manage.py startapp <app_name>
```